# ML Flow Export Import Tool - Registry URI

Tags: databricks, mlflow

I'm creating a pipeline that can copy a model version from one Databricks workspace to another one. They should be using the same unity catalog to store the model.

I'm trying to use the copy-model-version command from here
https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow-export-import/blob/master/README_copy.md

**I want to know what the registry URIs should be and how I find them**, here's a copy of the part of the pipeline for reference:

Thanks,

Cam

I have tried the workspaces URLs but this returned 403. This also does not match the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

403 - most likely you are not specifying the right token in you profile.

I want to know what the registry URIs should be and how I find them
See the link in the README; https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/cli/profiles.html

here's a copy of the part of the pipeline for reference:
Don't see it